# Global PHPunit no tests executed

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, bamboo

I have following phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php" backupGlobals="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="mentor">
            <directory>../module/Api</directory>
            <directory>../module/Application</directory>
            <exclude>../vendor</exclude>
          <exclude>vendor</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../module</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

file structure looks like this:

```
module
vendor
tests
-- phpunit.xml
-- Bootstrap.php
```

And now the tricky part. When I ran ../vendor/bin/php all works fine although if I ran global phpunit (/usr/local/bin/phpunit) it finishes with "no test executed" result. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using a Linux operating system like Ubuntu try: apt-get install phpunit

Comment: Include PHPUnit in your composer.json's require-dev section, and you'll get a vendor/bin/phpunit that will autoload all your composer stuff.

Comment: @RaviGehlot I was trying to run this using apt-get phpunit version although this for some reason ignores the vendor/autoload.php file and throws exceptions Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in ...

Comment: @AlexHowansky as I mention the vendors/bin/autoload works although I want to use my server phpunit instead

Comment: @Miroslaw What version of phpunit do you get when you run phpunit -V

Comment: PHPUnit 6.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Comment: _"although I want to use my server phpunit instead"_ Why? The version that composer installs is the version supported for the package you're working on, and it automatically handles autoloading.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I want to use newer version of phpunit and some packages in composer are limiting the maximum phpunit version therefore I can not use some functions of the phpunit 6 as I can use phpunit 5.7 only :(

Comment: If your project's composer.json limits PHPUnit to version 5.7, then you can't just run version 6.1 and expect it to work. You might try editing the composer.json and updating the requirement string to allow version 6+, then run `composer update` and see if the tests still work.

Comment: while using phpunit I'm testing my own classes not vendors (which require lower version of phpunit). Also all external services are mocked in my units so I'm pretty sure that those tests should work :)

Comment: _"I'm testing my own classes not vendors"_ Then you should have your own composer.json, in your own repository, with your own version requirements.

Comment: I think you misunderstood - I have repo with composer.json and all the vendors although those vendors limit the phpunit version. Anyway - going back to my original question - why global phpunit does not see any tests - is there anything missing or wrongly written in phpunit.xml?

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason why phpunit ommit all classes - that was due to TestCase I was trying to **extend**. All my tests relay on **\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase** from **Phpunit 5.7** package (in vendors). **Phpunit 6.1.4** use namespaces instead therefore I should extend **PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase**. By changing the extended class in tests all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use psr-4 inside composer like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "module/"
        }
}
```

After you need to change your phpunit.xml with this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php" backupGlobals="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="mentor">
            <directory>module/Api</directory>
            <directory>module/Application</directory>
            <exclude>../vendor</exclude>
          <exclude>vendor</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">module</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

I think you need to change your phpunit point to folder tests and not module!
 like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="Bootstrap.php" backupGlobals="false">
        <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="mentor">
                <directory>tests/</directory>
                <exclude>../vendor</exclude>
              <exclude>vendor</exclude>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
        <filter>
            <whitelist>
                <directory suffix=".php">tests</directory>
            </whitelist>
        </filter>
    </phpunit>
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help.

Comment: but you have specified that tests are under module, are you sure? aren't under folder tests??? @MirosławKarczmarczyk

Comment: same error. I have modules that includes i.e. Api, Application etc... which inside includes Test that are namespaced Api\Test\..., Application\Test\...